# Groupby / Summarize dataframe for every column except one column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (columnA - columnM):

```
columnA columnB .... columnK columnL columnM
A        AA     ....  10       AAA    AAAA
A        AA     ....  20       AAA    AAAA
B        BB     ....  5        BBB    BBBB
A        BB     ....  40       AAA    AAAA
...
```

How can I groupby the dataframe, that it calculates the `sum` for columnK by every group defined by all other columns, that it generates the output:

```
columnA columnB .... columnK columnL columnM
A        AA     ....  30       AAA    AAAA
B        BB     ....  5        BBB    BBBB
A        BB     ....  40       AAA    AAAA
...
```

for sure I can run the manuel command:

```
df.groupby(['columnA', 'columnB',...,'columnL', 'columnM'])['columnK'].sum().reset_index()
```

so I exclude the `columnK` in the first (), but is there a more pythonic way to do it? I keep all rows in the `groupby`function and use the some over the `columnK`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) or list comprehension for filtarion:

```
col = 'columnK'
df.groupby(list(df.columns.difference([col], sort=False)))[col].sum().reset_index()
```

Also if need original order of columns add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
col = 'columnK'
out = (df.groupby(list(df.columns.difference([col],sort=False)), as_index=False)[col].sum()
         .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
```

---

```
col = 'columnK'
out = (df.groupby([c for c in df.columns if c != col], as_index=False)[col].sum()
         .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
print (out)
  columnA columnB  columnK columnL columnM
0       A      AA       30     AAA    AAAA
1       A      BB       40     AAA    AAAA
2       B      BB        5     BBB    BBBB
```